# How to break down Strongly Connected Components (SCC) in a graph to obtain smaller and smaller nested cycles in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, strongly-connected-graph, kosaraju-algorithm

So I have been wondering about how to convert [complex graphs with nested cycles](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/03403d8950a84de799c53bdeb6c7c7bf) into simple Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAGs). I think I landed on the solution (not 100% sure). The solution is to use [Kosaraju's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm), which I have borrowed from [here](https://github.com/ivanmmarkovic/javascript-algorithms-data-structures/blob/d45ad2119b988e5013e174581f2919fb4f1143b8/graphs/kosaraju/kosaraju.js) in JavaScript, and got it working on that [first link's](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/03403d8950a84de799c53bdeb6c7c7bf) complex graph.

[image]

The code below isolates these SCCs:

```
[
  [ 'A' ],
  [ 'C' ],
  [ 'B' ],
  [
    'D', 'J', 'I',
    'H', 'F', 'E',
    'K', 'G'
  ],
  [ 'M' ],
  [ 'N' ],
  [ 'O' ],
  [ 'L' ]
]
```

The problem is, `D-J-I-H-F-E-K-G` actually contains *2 nested cycles* (shown in that first link), `F-G-K` and `H-I-J`. Is there any way to get this code to break down that 8-node SCC into like 4 smaller ones (`F-G-K`, `H-I-J`, `D`, `E`)? Is there any way to sort of recursively break down the SCCs so they isolate smaller and smaller SCCs? That would be great, because I am thinking how to do like a module system which handles circular dependencies, and if you can have small cycles compose into larger cycles, then you can parallelize some work. In the end, this Kosaraju algorithm at least identifies and returns the broadest cycles it seems in these initial tests, but I would like to get more exact and break down the cycles further if possible.

Is there any technique which can do this? If so, what should I be looking at, and or if you know how it is implemented that would be helpful to know as well.

Here is the Kosaraju algorithm code. The first `g1` graph is the image above, and the `g2` graph is just the 8-node SCC. I tried to run it on just that to see if it would recursively break it down, but sadly it doesn't.

```js
class Stack {
  constructor() {
    this.stack = [];
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this.stack.length == 0;
  }

  size() {
    return this.stack.length;
  }

  push(item) {
    this.stack.push(item);
  }

  pop() {
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
      throw new Error("Stack is empty");
    }
    return this.stack.pop();
  }

  peek() {
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
      throw new Error("Stack is empty");
    }
    return this.stack[this.stack.length - 1];
  }
}

class Graph {
  constructor() {
    this.vertices = new Set();
    this.adjacencyMap = new Map();
    this.adjacencyMapReversed = new Map();
    this.stack = new Stack();
    this.colors = new Map();
  }

  addVertex(vertex) {
    this.vertices.add(vertex);
    this.adjacencyMap.set(vertex, new Set());
    this.adjacencyMapReversed.set(vertex, new Set());
    this.colors.set(vertex, "white");
  }

  addEdge(v1, v2) {
    this.adjacencyMap.get(v1).add(v2);
    this.adjacencyMapReversed.get(v2).add(v1);
  }

  kosaraju() {
    for (let v of this.vertices) {
      if (this.colors.get(v) == "white") {
        this.dfs(v);
      }
    }

    for (let v of this.colors.keys()) {
      this.colors.set(v, "white");
    }

    let connected = [];

    while (!this.stack.isEmpty()) {
      let v = this.stack.pop();
      if (this.colors.get(v) == "white") {
        let c = [];
        this.dfsReversed(v, c);
        if (c.length > 0) {
          connected.push(c);
        }
      }
    }

    return connected
  }

  dfs(vertex) {
    this.colors.set(vertex, "gray");

    let neighbours = this.adjacencyMap.get(vertex);
    for (let n of neighbours) {
      if (this.colors.get(n) == "white") {
        this.dfs(n);
      }
    }

    this.colors.set(vertex, "black");
    this.stack.push(vertex);
  }

  dfsReversed(v, c) {
    this.colors.set(v, "gray");
    c.push(v);

    let neighbours = this.adjacencyMapReversed.get(v);
    for (let n of neighbours) {
      if (this.colors.get(n) == "white") {
        this.dfsReversed(n, c);
      }
    }

    this.colors.set(v, "black");
  }
}

const g1 = new Graph();

addV(g1, 'A')
addV(g1, 'B')
addV(g1, 'C')
addV(g1, 'D')
addV(g1, 'E')
addV(g1, 'F')
addV(g1, 'G')
addV(g1, 'H')
addV(g1, 'I')
addV(g1, 'J')
addV(g1, 'M')
addV(g1, 'N')
addV(g1, 'K')
addV(g1, 'L')
addV(g1, 'O')

addE(g1, 'A', ['B', 'C'])
addE(g1, 'B', ['D', 'G'])
addE(g1, 'C', ['D'])
addE(g1, 'D', ['E'])
addE(g1, 'E', ['F', 'K'])
addE(g1, 'F', ['G', 'H', 'M'])
addE(g1, 'G', ['H', 'L', 'N', 'K'])
addE(g1, 'H', ['I'])
addE(g1, 'I', ['J'])
addE(g1, 'J', ['D', 'H'])
addE(g1, 'M', ['O'])
addE(g1, 'N', ['O'])
addE(g1, 'K', ['L', 'F'])

console.log(g1.kosaraju());

// just the outer and inner cycles, not the rest:
const g2 = new Graph();

addV(g2, "D");
addV(g2, "E");
addV(g2, "F");
addV(g2, "G");
addV(g2, "H");
addV(g2, "I");
addV(g2, "J");
addV(g2, "K");

addE(g2, "D", ["E"]);
addE(g2, "E", ["F", "K"]);
addE(g2, "F", ["G", "H"]);
addE(g2, "G", ["H", "K"]);
addE(g2, "H", ["I"]);
addE(g2, "I", ["J"]);
addE(g2, "J", ["D", "H"]);
addE(g2, "K", ["F"]);

console.log(g2.kosaraju());

function addV(g, vertex) {
  g.addVertex(vertex);
}

function addE(g, vertex, edges) {
  edges.forEach((edge) => g.addEdge(vertex, edge));
}
```

Comment: I would suggest looking into the minimum feedback vertex set. But as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set says, that is NP complete to find. This would find the smallest number of modules to remove such that everything else can be loaded. Instead I would suggest simply banning circular dependencies.

Comment: "*Is there any way to sort of recursively break down the SCCs so they isolate smaller and smaller SCCs?*" - no non-ambiguous one, no. Consider the graph `A->B, B->C, C->A, A->D, D->C` - how would you break that down? What criteria do you want to apply?

Comment: Perhaps just pick any smaller cycles, and recursively do that? Doesn't have to be exact. Is it possible to have some heuristics on there?

Comment: @Bergi is there no way to take the provided output SCC from the algorithm, and run some other algorithms on it to find all nested/smaller-smaller cycles, and then filter them to a unique set or something?

Comment: Sure you can find all subgraphs that are strongly connected, but those are not necessarily non-overlapping. Like `A B C` and `C D A` in my example above. How to choose between them is up to you.

Comment: How do I then find all the subgraphs? Do I use something like the hamiltonian path finding algorithm or something like that? If I have all the subgraphs, perhaps I can just chunk them into groups using heuristics, such as starting with the smallest graphs, then working the way up to larger ones and matching to some set in a hash table or something.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two algorithms based on a depth first search traversal of the complex graph found in the question, highlighting the challenges of identifying subcycles as mentioned in @Bergi's comments to the question.

The first algorithm applies no heuristics, and simply captures all cycles found during the traversal.

The second algorithm, when finding a cycle, orders the chain by the least of the nodes, to eliminate cycles that are duplicate only because the cycle was traversed beginning with a different node in the chain.

```js
nodes = {
  a: [ 'b', 'c' ],
  b: [ 'd', 'g' ],
  c: [ 'd' ],
  d: [ 'e' ],
  e: [ 'f', 'k' ],
  f: [ 'g', 'h' , 'm' ],
  g: [ 'h', 'k', 'l', 'n' ],
  h: [ 'i' ],
  i: [ 'j' ],
  j: [ 'h', 'd' ],
  k: [ 'f', 'l' ],
  l: [],
  m: [ 'o' ],
  n: [ 'o' ],
  o: []
};



function findCyclesV1( rootNode) {

  function findCycles( node, chain ) {
    let n = chain.indexOf( node );
    if ( 0 <= n ) {
      result.add( chain.slice( n ) );
      return;
    } 
      
    chain += node;
    
    for ( let nextNode of nodes[ node ] ) {
      findCycles( nextNode, chain );
    }
  }
  
  let result = new Set();
  findCycles( rootNode, '' );
  return result;
}


function findCyclesV2( rootNode) {

  function findCycles( node, chain ) {
    let n = chain.indexOf( node );
    if ( 0 <= n ) {
      let subChain = chain.slice( n )

      // Normalize the chain by ensuring the lowest node is first.
      let leastNode = subChain.split('').reduce( ( t, c ) => t = c < t ? c : t );
      let m = subChain.indexOf( leastNode );
      
      result.add( subChain.slice( m ) + subChain.slice( 0, m ) );
      return;
    } 
      
    chain += node;
    
    for ( let nextNode of nodes[ node ] ) {
      findCycles( nextNode, chain );
    }
  }
  
  let result = new Set();
  findCycles( rootNode, '' );
  return result;
}

console.log( 'Algorithm 1: ', [ ...findCyclesV1( 'a' ) ].sort() );

console.log( 'Algorithm 2: ', [ ...findCyclesV2( 'a' ) ].sort() );
```

A couple of notables about the results of the second algorithm...

- The algorithm assumes that there is a root entry into the graph, that when traversed, can reach all nodes.
- Note that of the cycles `de...`, half are due to a side step to node `g` which is a node path slipped betwixt nodes `f` and `h`.  The same holds for node `k` which is a side step betwixt nodes `e` and `f`.
- Subcycle `hij` is easily recognizable in the `de...` cycles, but the same can't be said for subcycle `fgk`, which does appear in cycle `dekfghij`, but as `kfg`.  So any algorithm that attempts to draw out subcycles will have to take variations of the subcycle node order into consideration.

Given all of the above, the challenge is to define a data structure that allows for incorporation of sidesteps and subcycles.  In a regexp-ish like way, something along the following lines...

- `de[k*fg*|[kfg]][hij]`

...implying that the cycle must...

- `1)` begin with `de`, optionally followed by
- `2a)` `k*fg*` (where `k` and `g` are optional, and thus this is not a subcycle due to side steps) or
- `2b)` subcycle `kfg`, followed by
- `3)` subcycle `hij`...

Note also that it's not clear whether there will be other substructures that emerge from more complex graphs that will have to be taken into consideration when attempting to incorporate the cyclic flows into a compact data structure...

Comment: Looking interesting! At first glance it appears the output from both algorithm contains cycles which have nodes that were already used. How do you make it so the output has only cycles with no nodes in multiple cycles?

Comment: The output having cycles which don't share nodes is not possible given complex graphs.  @Bergi makes the point in his first comment to the question, showing a simple example where a number of nodes exist in two distinct cycles...  That's why in my answer I suggested the "regexp-ish" means of representing nested cycles and "side step" nodes.  If the nodes are objects rather than letters, then one can designate a node as either 1) belonging to a cycle, 2) a subcycle to parent cycle, or 3) a "side step" node to the main cycle...  But then `k` and 'g` will be both side step nodes and subcycles...